# How to implement language in geonetwork?

Tags: geonetwork, internationalization

How can I implement another language in Geonetwork 2.10.4? I have tried to follow this tutorial https://trac.osgeo.org/geonetwork/wiki/HowToTranslate, and in the section where are  described ISO19139 / Multilingual metadata and Translation of metadata schema labels, there is no such path as given in example. I have tried with changing code and haven't managed to fully impelemnt language. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several independent parts you need to translate to get a new language in GeoNetwork:

- Schemas: For each schema you want to use, you have to translate several files. Example: https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/2.10.x/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/data/config/schema_plugins/iso19139/loc/eng
- UI: Depending on what version of the UI you are using, you will need to translate different files. But on a general rule, you find what you need here:

https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/2.10.x/web/src/main/webapp/loc/eng/xml/
https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/2.10.x/web-client/src/main/resources/apps/js/GeoNetwork/lib/GeoNetwork/lang

By the way, you can help us in adding new languages for GeoNetwork 3 using transifex: https://www.transifex.com/signin/?next=/organization/geonetwork/dashboard It simplifies a lot the process of translating of version 2.10.x. And if made "official", you don't need to mess later with that.

Comment: The translation i have recieved is foreign language, and people who send mee, sent me files for Geonetwork 2.10.3. and i have implemented it succesfully. If i find time, i will make translation for my own country, so thanks for invitation.